# Save SELECT result for reusing in another SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any way to save the result of SQL request not as an array, but as a table object, that can be reused in other SQL requests?

For example, let me save the result of the request `(books tagged with 'c++')`

```
 SELECT BOOK 
 FROM BOOK_TAGS
 WHERE TAG = 'C++';
```

And then, for selecting books with tags 'c++' and 'gamedev' I don't want to scroll all BOOK_TAGS table again, I'd like to select them from the previously saved result

Something like

```
SELECT BOOK 
FROM $TAGGED JOIN BOOK_TAGS USING(BOOK)
WHERE TAG = 'gamedev';
```

Comment: hint : use 'with'

Comment: Create a view?  Use a disconnected record set?  use a derived table?

Comment: All of those options address the xy problem; if you're just trying to identify all books that have both the C++ tag and the gamedev tag; then writing a single query will do the trick

Comment: How long would you need to save the result? I see you tagged with PHP, so are you thinking of persisting the result over multiple requests?

Comment: @DanielMarcus both select's are meant to be executed with an interval of time between them

Comment: @Don'tPanic within a single static page

Comment: You could cache the result in another table or a file, CSV, JSON whatever. I guess you want this for furure comparisons? I think I would store my ids in a json file and then in the other queries I would where book in(list of ids) and tag='gamedev'.. Or you could create another table.

Comment: @Lou ye, I just was looking for any built-in way

Comment: The only way I can see doign this is saving the 1st query as a view to the database.  Since you can't combine the SQL engine to the local PHP server; having the 2nd action take place on the database would either require a create table to store the results or a view. you would then reference this view/table as needed in the next statement and then delete it when done.  Seems like alot of work. Though don't understand the "time" requirement between the two queries I guess.

Comment: If you only need to save it within the current database session, use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fell into the XY problem in comments but when I saw some of the other answers I reconsidered the problem:

If your goal is to return all books with having both tags...

```
SELECT book
FROM book_tags
WHERE tag in ('C++', 'gamedev')
GROUP BY Book
HAVING count(Distinct tag) =2
```

Note: I use distinct incase a tag can be duplicated for a book; if the table design prevents such duplicates then the distinct should not be used.

OR:

1. Create a view based on the 1st query
2. Create a table with the results (this way results don't change as they would 
   in a view

.

```
Create table RandomKey as (
SELECT BOOK 
 FROM BOOK_TAGS
 WHERE TAG = 'C++');
```

and then later

```
SELECT BOOK 
FROM randomkey JOIN BOOK_TAGS USING(BOOK)
WHERE TAG = 'gamedev';
```

but I don't like changing structure on the fly like this.

Comment: Was not stated to approach this :) Was actually seeking for saving both results

Comment: Then I'm back to a view (materialized or w/ filter) or disconnected recordset (not sure this is viable in PHP)

Comment: @xQbert I think you forgot the `group by` on that first one.

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily save almost any result by creating a table to store it in.

The simplest way is:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `blah` 
SELECT ....
;
```

The benefit of this way is that *temporary* tables are only visible on the current database connection, and automatically cleaned up when that connection is closed. However, they cannot be used as freely as normal tables (no self-joins, cannot be referenced twice in a UNION, etc...)

You could use non-temporary tables, but they are visible across connections so you risk multiple clients manipulating them simultaneously, and they are persistent so you have to make sure you clean them up yourself (and that they get cleaned up properly after connection losses as well).

The downside to both of these is that there is no automatic indexing, so often you end up having to be more formal with such "cache" tables' creation, and then use `INSERT .... SELECT`. Often, at this point, it becomes more trouble than it is worth unless you're going through all this to fix performance issues in an existing single query.

For queries as simple as you've presented, there is usually no real benefit to saving the results like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table variable, but why not combine into one query? You're query optimizer should do the work to make sure it isn't inefficient:

```
SELECT BOOK
FROM BOOK_TAGS
WHERE 
    TAG = 'C++' 
    OR
    TAG = 'gamedev'
```

It also seems like you're leaving something out. Are you meaning to select from a `BOOKS` table that has a many-to-many relationship with a `TAGS` table (with `BOOK_TAGS` being the join table)?

Comment: a record couldn't be both but this may be along the right lines

Comment: Nope then it will not be both.

Comment: @xQbert I think the question is missing some information. It can't be both as posed.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you mean but 
all request from sql is table object

```
SELECT BOOK FROM BOOK_TAGS WHERE TAG = 'C++' AND TAG = 'gamedev';
```

give you only book with both tag